# Changing content of preamble.tex based on params in YAML header in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to run reprocucible parametrized reports in Rmarkdown and have two parameters set: center (the facility to run the report for) and language (either German or French).

In my YAML-header I included two tex-files (preamble & before_body) that have language or center specific adaption, but I call the params later in the report. Until now I have to change those 5 lines manually before running the report - it is manageable but not "safe". I'm curious if there would be a programming way of adapting those texts, so that only the params$center need to be changed?

the yaml-header in the main file looks like this - adaptions for the report are made in `center` and `language`:

```
---
fontsize: 11pt
linestretch: 1.0
link-citations: yes
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
      before_body: before_body.tex
      after_body: after_body.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
    keep_tex: true
documentclass: report
subparagraph: yes
params:
   center: 148
   language: "D"
   date: !r lubridate::today()
title: Report center `r params$center`, `r lubridate::month(params$date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE,
  locale = {if (params$language == "D") {"de_CH.UTF-8"} else {"fr_FR.UTF-8"}})` `r lubridate::year(params$date)`
---
```

the preamble.tex looks like this - adaptions for language need to be made with `\usepackage[german]{babel}` and  `\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}`:

```
% loading necessary LateX-packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

% set column widths for tabularx
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.7\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{X}

% include a fancy header
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\setlength\headheight{100pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{img/INS_logo.png}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=4.1cm]{img/shurp-2018-logo-blue-transparent.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{plain}


% define landscape mode 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}

% set page geometry
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=40mm}

% make the word "Chapter" disappear - only display the chapters name
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

% % Following below
% turns maketitle off, then you can define your own titlepage in before_body.tex
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}
```

the before_body.tex looks like this (titlepage pdf with design), adaptions need to be made in `\includepdf[pages={1}]{img/SHURP-Report-Cover-DE-1901.pdf}` (-DE- is transformed to -FR-):

```
% titlepage included by pdf
\includepdf[pages={1}]{img/SHURP-Report-Cover-DE-1901.pdf}


% this line includes a page with the title: TEXT from the YAML-header - if you
%  dont need that, rm or better comment it (wont be evaluated then)
\let\maketitle\oldmaketitle
\maketitle
```

I could even automatize the params$language (centers with an ID < 250 are german and above are French speaking) - I left it to be aware of changing the other documents.

Additionally, the second page has now as title: "Report center (center), Month, Year" but the part "Report center (center)" should be replaced by the actual center name and address (that is stored in another file). Until now I just changed it by hand in Acrobat in the end.

Is there a way of doing that more elegantly? In some of my other questions someone mentioned `knitr::knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) { }` to change the .tex file of the whole document before compiling it - but I did not understand how that works.

Comment: Easy way would be to alter the default pandoc pdf tempalte and include it via `template: mytemplate.tex`. In the default tempalte you can add your extra code using variables. E.g. this file could be used: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex

Comment: thanks - I did not know about this feature but will definitely look into it with https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/document-templates.html and https://github.com/dr-harper/example-rmd-templates